# UIButton should fire a method once in 24hrs

Tags: ios4, uibutton

sorry for the question.I have to save the time when the button is clicked for

the first time and then compare the time with the future time and if it is greater than or

equal to the same time I have to fire a method or else an alert.

Here is the code.

```
-(IBAction)checkInButtonClicked
{
    now = [NSDate date];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:now forKey:@"theFutureDate"];

    NSTimeInterval timeToAddInDays = 60 * 60 * 24;
    theFutureDate = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeToAddInDays];

    switch ([now compare:theFutureDate]){
    case NSOrderedAscending:{
    NSLog(@"NSOrderedAscending");

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Oops! The Check In will activate after 24Hrs"] 
    delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil ];
    [alert show];
    }
    break;
    case NSOrderedSame:{
    NSLog(@"NSOrderedSame");
    [self insertPoints];
   }
    break;
    case NSOrderedDescending:{
    NSLog(@"NSOrderedDescending");
   }
    break;
   }
  }
```

But this code is not working exactly.Can anyone please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what way is the code not working?

Comment: No,it didn't work exactly as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're comparing always `now` with a future date. That comparison has always the same result.

If I understood correctly you want exactly the other way around. You must compare `now` with the first time the user clicked the button. So you set the date in `NSUserDefaults` only the first time and make comparisons the second and subsequent times.

```
- (IBAction)checkInButtonClicked {     
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *firstTimeClicked = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"firstTimeClicked"];
    if (firstTimeClicked) {
        /* this is at least the second time the button has been clicked */        
        NSTimeInterval delta = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:firstTimeClicked];
        if (delta > 24 * 3600) {
            /* button clicked > 1 day ago */
        } else {
            /* button clicked <= 1 day ago */
        }
    } else {
        /* not present in NSUserDefaults, it's first click */
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:now forKey:@"firstTimeClicked"];   
    }
}
```